# Selecting divs using attribute conditions Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.sameClass{
  background-color:#3e6687;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#first,#second{
  margin-bottom:10px;
  float:left;
}

#first{
  background-color:#8a94ae;
}

#second{
  background-color:#29375a;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
<div class="sameClass" data-category="fun"></div>
<div class="sameClass" data-category="boring"></div>
<div class="sameClass" data-category="okay"></div>
</div>

<div id="second">
<div class="sameClass" data-category="fun"></div>
<div class="sameClass" data-category="boring"></div>
<div class="sameClass" data-category="okay"></div>
</div>


<input type="button" value="Lets Do This">
```

Lets say I have the code above and I want to insert an image dynamically into one of those divs when a button has been clicked. I would like to check if the div has attribute class="sameClass" and attribute data-category="fun". The third condition is that this attribute has to be in div with attribute id="second".

I want to do this with jQuery. Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```js
$(":button").on("click", function() {
  //according your requirements element with class .sameClass and 
  //data-category = fun that ancestor element has id second
  $("#second div.sameClass[data-category='fun']").append("<div>test</div>");
});
```

```css
.sameClass {
  background-color: #3e6687;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#first,
#second {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
}
#first {
  background-color: #8a94ae;
}
#second {
  background-color: #29375a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
  <div class="sameClass" data-category="fun"></div>
  <div class="sameClass" data-category="boring"></div>
  <div class="sameClass" data-category="okay"></div>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <div class="sameClass" data-category="fun"></div>
  <div class="sameClass" data-category="boring"></div>
  <div class="sameClass" data-category="okay"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Lets Do This">
```

Comment: Why wrap that in `[class='sameClass']` when `.` notation exists?

Comment: And your edit makes my comment look stupid.  `+1` for the same answer.

Comment: this works too.. thanks. Didnt know about the [] way of doing things.

Comment: Yes you can take a look [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [w3 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)

Answer (score 3):

There are CSS selector options for all of the conditions you listed, and jQuery accepts CSS selectors to select elements (for what it's worth, so does the latest ECMA specs for native JavaScript).

You would do your given scenario like this:

```
$('div#second div.sameClass[data-category="fun"]') /* Your element */
```

You could then append an image tag to that, or otherwise alter it any way you'd like.

Comment: great @Josh i was extra work so deleted my answer as this one is correct

Answer (score 0):

The selector can be like this

```js
$('input[type=button]').on('click', function(){
     $('div#second').find('.sameClass[data-category="fun"]').append('<div>Test</div>');
});
```

```css
.sameClass {
  background-color: #3e6687;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#first,
#second {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
}
#first {
  background-color: #8a94ae;
}
#second {
  background-color: #29375a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
    <div class="sameClass" data-category="fun"></div>
    <div class="sameClass" data-category="boring"></div>
    <div class="sameClass" data-category="okay"></div>
</div>

<div id="second">
    <div class="sameClass" data-category="fun"></div>
    <div class="sameClass" data-category="boring"></div>
    <div class="sameClass" data-category="okay"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Lets Do This">
```